# Regexp_replace in PySpark to replace middle double quote from a string

Tags: pyspark, regexp-replace

need to remove only middle "(quote) character from a given string, start and end quote will be always there:-

InputString= '"pyspark"Data"'
Outputstring = '"pyspark Data"'

only the middle "(quote) is removed from the string

other example:-

'"google"chrome"' => '"google chrome"'

'"master"file"name"' => '"master file name"'

'"google"chrome"' => '"google chrome"'

'"master"file"name"' => '"master file name"'

Answer (score 0):

Replace all the quotes then enclose the normalized string again in quotes

```
df.withColumn('col', F.expr(""" '"' || trim(regexp_replace(col, '"', ' ')) || '"' """))
```

---

```
+------------------+
|               col|
+------------------+
|   "google chrome"|
|"master file name"|
|   "google chrome"|
|"master file name"|
+------------------+
```

Comment: this a work around, but looking for exact regular expression to remove middle character except first and last

Comment: I would not say this is a workaround. I believe this is somewhat robust method.